# How can I use concat operator in RxJS, but ignore all of the emissions from the first observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive

Let's say we have 2 observables.

const obs1 =  timer(1000);
const obs2 = of(1,2,3)

If I'd like to wait until obs1 completes I could obviously use concat operator.

obs1.pipe(concat(obs2)).subscribe(console.log);

or

concat(obs1, obs2).subscribe(console.log);

It would work fine (the order is preserved), but the '0' emitted from the first obs would still be logged. Is there a way to force certain subscriptions' order, but ignore emissions from the given observable? (e.g. only values from the last observable in 'chain' should be seen).

In this particular case I know how many values to expect, so I could simply use skip/takeLast, but I'm looking for a generic solution, which doesn't require me to know the amount of elements emitted from observables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use just `ignoreElements()`.

```
concat(obs1.pipe(ignoreElements()), obs2).subscribe(...)
```

It doesn't matter whether `obs1` emits any `next` notifications or not. `obs1` just needs to complete.

Comment: what if i would like to take the last emitted value instead of completely ignoring all values from obs1?

Comment: Theres takeLast operator

Answer (score 1):

Use the combineLatest:

Example:

```
    import { timer, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
   const timerOne$ = timer(1000, 4000);
   const timerTwo$ = timer(2000, 4000);
   const timerThree$ = timer(3000, 4000);
   combineLatest(timerOne$, timerTwo$, timerThree$).subscribe(
  ([timerValOne, timerValTwo, timerValThree]) => {

    console.log(Timer Three Latest: ${timerValThree}`
    );
  }
);
```

or

```
import { timer, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

const timerOne$ = timer(1000, 4000);
const timerTwo$ = timer(2000, 4000);
const timerThree$ = timer(3000, 4000);

combineLatest(
  timerOne$,
  timerTwo$,
  timerThree$,
  // combineLatest also takes an optional projection function
  (one, two, three) => {
    return `${three}`;
  }
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either `switchMap` or log the values in the pipeline of just the second observable:

```
const obs1 = timer(1000);
const obs2 = of(1, 2, 3);

obs1.pipe(
  concat(obs2.pipe(tap(val => console.log(val))))
).subscribe();

obs1.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => obs2)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: tap would work, but I'd like to see these values in subscribe()
How could I use switchMap in this case though? I'm not sure it's applicable in this scenario